# I want two inline-block vertical center in a outside-div through transform way

Tags: html, css

I write html like this

```
<div class="outside-div">
<div class="inside-div1">
<div class="inside-div2">
</div>

css like this:
.outside-div{
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
font-size: 0px;
}

.inside-div1{
width:100px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
display: inline-block;
}

.inside-div2{
width:100px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
display: inline-block;
}
```

as we know, we can vertical center a inside-div(display: inline-block) inside a outside-div through transform way, but if I add a new inside-div, I find the first inside-div position will be change, it looks like relative the second inside-div.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 inside-div are overtaking each other.. Your inside-div2 overtakes the inside-div1 and hence you are not able to see the inside-div1. If you remove one of them you will see your another div is still right behind it. Here i have done some modification, that separates both the div.

Also, try removing one div at a time.. and you will get to know the divs are right behind each other.

```css
.outside-div{
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
font-size: 0px;
background:black;
}

.inside-div1{
width:100px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
display: inline-block;
background:red;
}

.inside-div2{
width:100px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
display: inline-block;
background:yellow;
margin-left:200px;
}
```

Comment: how to make two inside div vertical center in outside div use top + transform.  i know i can add a div(height: 100%) wrapper inside div to solve this problem